# Blender only masks the outline of what I'm trying to mask

Tags: masking

I am still very new to Blender Stack Exchange so if I deviate from the format that is because I don't really know this.

**Problem**:
When I mask out something (in this case, an arm), it only masks the outline and doesn't fill it in. Here is some images of the problem:

[image: Masked Arm]

*ps: I am still learning the basics of masking so it is a bit bad of a mask...*

[image: The Mask Viewer only shows the outline of the mask and the final render is just the outline as well]

I hope someone can help me with this and maybe the format of this website a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that the direction of the mask was flipped. Selecting the mask and switching the direction fixed the problem.

For some reason I had this problem again and this didn't work. Maybe there are different ways to solve different problems with the same look or something, I don't know, its weird.

Comment: This only works for some of them, I had this problem again and doing this didn't work.